# Display URL as an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, high-level

Basically I have a field called "Google Street View" which contains the URL of an image.

I would like to display that URL as an image, but I have 2 issues:

1. I can't modify the code of the site itself (i.e. adding img tags to the field), I can only add JS in the header or at the top of the body.
2. The field and surrounding divs don't have any unique properties or names.  The only unique property of this specific field is the name "Google Street View"

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <!----><span data-v-56639245="" class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 capitalize">Google Street View</span>
  <div picklistoptions="" picklistoptionsimage="" field="[object Object]"><input type="text" data-lpignore="true" autocomplete="" placeholder="" class="hl-text-input shadow-sm focus:ring-curious-blue-500 focus:border-curious-blue-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded disabled:opacity-50 text-gray-800"></div>
</div>
```

no clue what I'm doing

Comment: You want to convert the string `https://www.somesite.com/someimage.jpg`  to an image of the same string?

Comment: `<img src=yourValue>`?